# Why not generalize the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition

So I know the IVT says that given a continuous function on a closed interval [a,b] then if $f(a) < \gamma <f(b)$ then there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = \gamma$.

Is there any reason for not replacing the image of the end-points with the image of the maximum and minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$. In other words, why isn't the mean value theorem stated as above but with $f(a)$ replaced by the minimum value of $f$ taken on $[a,b]$ and similarly $f(b)$ replaced with the maximum value of $f$ taken on $[a,b]$?

Comment: It would also make the theorem harder to apply. Determining the max/min of a function is more difficult than just evaluating it at the end points.

Comment: @Spencer Not sure why it would be harder to apply. If $f(a) < \gamma < f(b),$ then clearly $m < \gamma < M$  without knowing the exact values of $m,M.$

Comment: Well, the most generalized generalization is that the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected as well.

Comment: Contrary to what @mixedmath wrote, I don't think your suggested version is weaker. My best guess as to why it hasn't replaced the standard version is that it presupposes the theorem that continuous functions *have* maximum and minimum values on a closed interval.  It seems neater to keep that theorem and the IVT separate (because they're based on separate ideas --- compactness and connectedness) rather than mixing them together by making one presuppose the other.

Comment: @AndreasBlass this seems makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I spoke too soon, and I've removed my earlier comment.